# ASP.NET C# Hyperlinks depending on roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

I have my Site set up with 2 different roles and then of course the anonymous one.
I have a hyperlink for logged in users to go to their account page but I want the same hyperlink to be different for each role. For Example

If the role is Admin I want the Link "My Account" to go to admin/myaccount.aspx
If the role is seller I want the Link "My Account" to go to seller/myaccount.aspx

I have used a link button and plan on adding ifs to the C# but im unsure how to make an if based on the roles any idea?

Mark

Comment: I would advice against using this construct. For eample, when a user gets a new role, he may not see the new account part when he relies on bookmarks. Are you sure that this is what you want? Why not use the same url for all users (/account), and let the page customize itself based on the role(s) the user is in? You can then use the answer from @Pepto below to customize the page (show or hide controls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Forms Authentication -

```
System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal _user = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
            if (_user.IsInRole("admin"))
            {
                //Set link to admin link
            }
            else
            {
                //Set to other link
            }
```

More info on IsInRole: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.isinrole.aspx

Comment: Hi Pepto thanks for the help. I have inserted the code you added but at the moment I have a admin user but it doesn't work for them and just uses the else statement, I assume i have to add something before it but unsure what any ideas?

Comment: It's important that the string name you use for the role name matches exactly what it is you are looking for. If using Forms Authentication this would be assigned typically by your own custom role provider. If using Window's based authentication, it will usually begin with "BUILTIN\". I'm afraid there isn't enough space to fully cover creating roles on an Principal. Please view http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wefzhcez(v=VS.71).aspx for a good head start on this topic

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches with ASP.NET, using [HyperLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx) control:

1. Use two [HyperLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx) controls with same caption "My Account" but have different [NavigateUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.navigateurl.aspx) property. Check user's role and dynamically set the correct link [visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.visible.aspx) in Page_Load function.
2. Use one [HyperLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx) control with caption "My Account", and set the correct [NavigateUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.navigateurl.aspx) property in Page_Load function.